# Node command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, avr

I'm trying to install avrgirl-arduino using the command `sudo npm install avrgirl-arduino`. When I try running the command `avrgirl-arduino list` I get an error saying `-bash: avrgirl-arduino: command not found`. I ran `npm init` before running the first command and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to install your package [globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) :

```
npm install -g avrgirl-arduino
```

This way you can use command line tool package (like grunt)

Comment: I tried the things above on a terminal on c9.io and it worked, seems weird why it won't work on my Mac. I'll try this later as I don't have my Mac right now.